# Is the Hebrew Biur of Moses Mendelssohn Available Online

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, commentaries, pentateuch-chumash

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59189/moses-mendelssohn-permitted-to-quote-him), I was wondering whether the Hebrew Biur of Moses Mendelssohn is available online.

**Update:** I found D'varim [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=QNk0AAAAIAAJ&pg=PT2&dq=Netivot%20ha-Shalom&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false), so I am looking for the first 4 books.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are all available here:

[Bereishis](http://books.google.com/books?id=EUE-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PT4#v=onepage&q&f=false%20Shemot%20http://books.google.com/books?id=0ZosAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA1&dq=%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D&hl=en&ei=lmdHToi5NIO5tgf-joH5BQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[Shemos](http://books.google.com/books?id=0ZosAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA1&dq=%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D&hl=en&ei=lmdHToi5NIO5tgf-joH5BQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[Vayikra](http://books.google.com/books?id=8qpAAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9%20%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D&hl=en&ei=2WlHTsW3I4G6tgfZ2eDnBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[Bemidbar](http://books.google.com/books?id=1jg7AAAAcAAJ&pg=PP9#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[Devarim](http://books.google.com/books?id=klItAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D&hl=en&ei=t2ZHTvvvIYGDtgen57HyBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Shmot is [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=DL9DAQAAMAAJ) and [here](https://archive.org/details/miraeodeshsefern00mend).

VaYikra is [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=8Ds7AAAAcAAJ).