# During the time when the Sanhedrin was primarily Sadducees, would the average citizen that believed in the Oral Law have to listen to them?

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy

During the reign of Alexander Yannai, the court was mostly Sadducees (Sanhedrin 52b, other places) before Shimon Ben Shetach returned and was able to remove them.

During the period before Shimon Ben Shetach returned, assuming there was a majority of Sadducees, would someone that believed in the Pharisses/Oral Law be obligated to obey their heretical judgements since during that time they were the Sanhedrin?

Comment: No. Horayot is all about what happens if the sanhedrin err and one knows that they err.

Comment: The Gemara there is talking about a Beis Din, not the Sanhedrin.

Comment: @HaLeivi Rambam refers to that beis din as beis din hagadol

Comment: The gemara there is talking about sanhedrin.the whole question about par heelem davar is by sanhedrin

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59921/can-one-cite-divrei-torah-in-the-name-of-a-rabbi-who-has-gone-astray

Comment: @joshwaxman The OP didn't really (at least explicitly) mention that the court was known to have erred, just that they were not Pharisees.

Comment: But if they are basing themselves only on written law, then the pharisee knows they are erring and, according to the gemara, is prohibited from listening to them

Comment: @user6591 Where does the Rambam discuss the Beis Din Hagadol having been Tzedukim?

Comment: @HaLeivi the gemara you mentioned as talking about a regular B.D. is actually talking about the Beis Din Hagadol as mentioned explicitly in the Rambam.

Comment: @user6591 I didn't bring up any Gemara. I am referring to Sanhedrin 52 which was mentioned by the OP, and is not about He'elem Davar. I am asking from where is the assumption that at any point was the Sanhedrin overtaken by Tzedukim. I don't think that is the case.

Comment: @HaLeivi gotcha. I thought you were responding to Josh. My bad.

Comment: @joshwaxman That assumes that the average citizen knew enough about the specific ruling to know that it was specifically based on this assumption of the Sadducee judges (and that knowledge of errant reasoning is as valid as knowledge of an errant conclusion - which may be plausible anyway...)

Comment: @HaLeiVi - Josephus specifically says that the Sadducees were running everything during Alexander Jannai's reign.

Comment: @Gary That doesn't necessarily include Sanhedrin which is about Halacha, not government control. The Gemara seems to describe the Sanhedrin as a normal functioning Sanhedrin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Talmud (Moed Katan 17a) infers from a verse in Malachi (2:7) that a rabbi only has authority inasmuch as his active choices reflect the values and teachings of the Torah:

> ההוא צורבא מרבנן דהוו סנו שומעניה. א"ר יהודה: היכי ליעביד - לשמתיה צריכי ליה רבנן, לא לשמתיה קא מיתחיל שמא דשמיא? א"ל לרבב"ח: מידי שמיע לך בהא? א"ל: הכי א"ר יוחנן: מאי דכתיב (מלאכי ב, ז) "כי שפתי כהן ישמרו דעת ותורה יבקשו מפיהו כי מלאך ה' צבאות הוא" - אם דומה הרב למלאך ה' יבקשו תורה מפיו ואם לאו אל יבקשו תורה מפיו
>
> There was one young scholar concerning whom evil rumors were current.
>   Said R' Yehuda: "What shall be done in this case? Shall we put him
>   under the ban? The rabbis need him. Shall we not? The name of Heaven
>   will be profaned." And he asked Rabba bar bar Hana: "Do you know
>   anything about such a case?" He answered him: So said R' Yohanan: "It
>   is written (Malachi 2:7): 'The priest's lips are ever to keep
>   knowledge, and the law are they to seek from his mouth, for he is the
>   *malach* (angel) of the Lord of hosts.' That means: If the Master is equal
>   to an *malach*, law may be sought from his mouth, but not otherwise."

The Sadducees were a heretical sect and therefore had no standing as halachic authorities and it would be forbidden to treat them as such. See also: https://www.ou.org/jewish_action/06/2015/halachah-and-the-fallen-rabbi-q-a-with-rabbi-hershel-schachter/

Comment: The sinner in the passage is interpreted as having given in to sexual temptations. However, the argument is even stronger with regard to ideological sins such as those committed by the Sadduccees (e.g. as revealed by the more severe approach of halacha toward the meshumad l'hachis [ideological sinner] relative to the meshumad l'teiavon [sinner from desire].)

Comment: I think your comment belongs in the answer.