# How should I learn Tanach?

Tags: torah-study, tanach

I was learning the Maharal on Avos and he strongly denounces the commonly-practised Yeshiva system in use in the Ashkenazic world. Specifically, he complains about starting to learn gemara-rashi-tosafos at a  young age. He says he has seen many great Bachurim who could have been very great-- end up ignoramuses through this system.

The present system for Chumash covers maybe one parsha a year. Even that is at a surface level.  Very little Nach is studied. A long time is spent on a few pages of gemara. Even in Bekiyus we finish only one masechta in a year without doing Rashi.

This method seems to reduce the possibility of students learning seforim on their own.

Do the sources or contemporary Rabbonim offer methods of study that develop the possibility of their students being able to study independently?

Comment: **I was learning the maharal on Avos and he had highly denounced the commonly-practiced Yeshiva system in use in the Ashkenazic world.** - I do want to point out that the custom didn't change despite the Maharal.

Comment: http://www.mastertorah.com/newsite/general/index.php?page=tanach_about ?

Comment: Since your are asking for suggestions, start by reading through tanach in English, is spite of the potentially contrary advice. Remember that although there is much to learn, you have a lifetime ahead of you. By deciding what you wish to learn, and making a schedule to learn it, you are basically guaranteed to accomplish quite a bit. Over a few years toy can definitely read through the whole tanach in English and learn at least most chumash-rashi-ramban. You can also go systematically through kitzur shulchan aruch for practical halacha. Moving on, or concurrently, you can learn the whole

Comment: Mishna using English aids. This will take a few years, but is very doable and will provide excellent background. Hatslaha rabba!

Comment: So you want advice for learning nach in Hebrew b/c a certain Rebbi said not to use English but you want to learn nach in a different way than is taught by that rebbi b/c of a statement by the maharal? Or perhaps I am misunderstanding what you are saying? It seems like perhaps before proceeding how you should learn nach you might want to understand what your learning objectives should be by consulting your mashpia

Comment: For more sources on the essntial nature of studying Tanakh, see Riaz (Kiddushin 1:7:8), Yesh Nohalin of the Shelah's brother, the Shelah's commentary to Shevuot (chapter Ner Mitsvah: 22), Rabbi Sh'lomo Kluger in Shu"t Haelef L'kha Shelomo (YD 259), Bach (YD 245), P'ri Megadim (letter 5), Shu"t Afrakasta D'anya (vol. I: 194), Shut Torah Lishma (254), Shu"t Shevet Halevi (vol. VIII: 207), Hida in D'vash L'pi (ת 41), Shemot Rabba (Ki Tisa 41), Shir HaShirim Rabba: 4, Rashi to Exodus (31:18).

Comment: I edited and simplified your question to focus on an answer from sources or contemporary Rabbonim and not on opinion. Feel free to roll it back.

Comment: `I was learning the Maharal on Avos and he had highly denounced the commonly-practiced Yeshiva system in use in the Ashkenazic world.` Can you source this? Also, do we follow everything the Maharal said?

Comment: Interesting to note that traditionally, the yekkish yeshivos studied Tanach as well as Talmud

Comment: This might sound a bit strange to some, but I would suggest getting a Stone Edition Tanach and just reading through the Neviim and Ketuvim, delving into commentary along the way.  Read through it multiple times and just get a good feel for the text.

Comment: You say the "present system" covers one parsha a year. Many schools I know do much more than that. Perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: I don't mean to speak against learning Nach, nor to disagree with the Maharal. But indeed the standard yeshivah system doesn't emphasize it today, and there are reasons for that. I'm not sure that just quoting the Maharal is enough. Plus, you didn't mention Mishnayos, and that is an even more obvious pre-requisite for learning Gemara.

Comment: Of course, learning Tanach is a good thing. But it may not be a good idea to do it "because the Maharal denounced..."

Answer (score 2):

I would reccommend for learning Tanakh to try and learn 2 chapters a day. Azamra.com has an excellent program called Know Your Bible where they send out a daily email with commentary from classic jewish sources on 2 chapters. In this way you will finish all Tanakh in about a year and have an excellent foundation.

http://www.azamra.org/spirit/nakh.php

I also reccommend Rabbi Rosner on the OU Torah App, he gives 20 min shiurim on Nach great to listen to while driving.

Comment: Welcome to MY. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Your first paragraph should be a comment on the other answer (you will be able to comment once you reach 50 points). The rest of your answer doesn't really answer the question (which sources or contemporary Rabbonim offer methods of study that develop the possibility of their students being able to study independently?). Hope to see you around though !

Comment: I will move your first para in the right place otherwise your answer will receive many downvotes

Comment: Since the q doesn't ask for personal advice I'll just comment to this post: I greatly benefited from the 2 chap/day approach. I followed tanachyomi.co.il, but I don't think which one you choose matters that much. I tried once w/ english and found myself bogged down, constantly wanting to check the Hebrew. It's always important to know yourself. I liked metzudos for Neviim rishonim and selectively peeking at  Daat mikra for harder books. Having a translation handy is also important, but for independence I've benefited from something that explains the forms so you can get a sense of the language

Answer (score 1):

Rav [Meir Pogrow](http://www.mastertorah.com/newsite/general/index.php?page=ravmeirpogrow) has an interesting program seen [here](http://www.mastertorah.com/newsite/general/index.php?page=tanach_about) where he offers two different methods of learning and reviewing Tanach. He also provides the [shiurim](http://www.mastertorah.com/newsite/shiurim/tanach/tanach_FS.pdf) and tests to cover all of the material as well.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59921/8775.

Comment: User Tevye notes that Meir Pogrow has been denounced by the leading Rabbis as a Rasha, and it is forbidden to learn Torah from him, see [here](http://www.jpost.com/Israel-News/Prominent-rabbi-and-educator-accused-of-grooming-abuse-of-power-457329) (he doesn't yet have enough points to post this directly)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the [Daily Nach](http://dailynach.com/) system which was started here in the UK to encourage regular nach learning and has since spawned a couple of seforim and a whole programme of learning.

They describe themselves as follows:

> The Daily Nach programme was started in September 2007 by two Hasmonean boys to encourage the learning of Nach. It aimed to help people gain a basic understanding of the whole of Nach.  Nach is one of the parts of Torah which is seemingly neglected from our learning schedule. Nach is a critical part of Torah which contains  many lessons for us today and it contains our history.
>
> All participants of the program learn the same Perek of Nach each day in their own time. The group receive a Dvar Torah and  Perek summaries on the perokim in Nach which they are learning via e-mail every week. In addition, there is a weekly Chabura in the boy’s school and fornightly in the girl’s. The program has expanded and grown with Hashem’s help. It now has branches both in London and Israel as it continues into its’ fourth cycle. The program now has dozens of participants across the globe.
>
> The programme is tough and needs persistence in order to keep up to date, but is very rewarding and highly recommended for everyone to take up. Although the program is run by Hasmonean students, we encourage everyone worldwide to participate and join the program.

For every book of Nach there are shiurim (e.g. [Yehoshua](http://dailynach.com/yehoshua-shiurim/)), summaries (e.g. [Yehoshua](http://dailynach.com/summaries-divrei-torah/joshua/yechezkelsummary/)) and divrei Torah (e.g. [Yehoshua](http://dailynach.com/summaries-divrei-torah/joshua/yehoshuadivrei-torah/)). And recently they launched an 'Inside Nach' option which provides more in-depth analysis e.g. [Koheles](http://dailynach.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Inside-Nach-Koheles-Perek-1.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

How should you learn Tanach? Depends what you want to get out of it. There's many ways to answer the question. However, one way I can tell you to learn, how I learn is through my Rebbe, Rabbi Efraim Goldstein. This is a link to his shuirim. He's a major Talmud Chochum who has semicha from great gedolim in Yoreh Yoreh and Yadin Yadin and he happens to also be a great mekubal.
He goes through Tanach which Rashi and most times with the GR"A. Also, he brings in Rav וואלי Pshat sometimes. L'maseh it's a very Geshmak and very much Machshava focused with Penimuis Hatorah built in based off Rishonim etc. Give it try.

http://jewishheritagefoundation.org/tanach.html