# May you repeat the words of a rasha?

Tags: sources-mekorot, evil-resha

I vaguely remember reading that a rabbi ruled that the words of a rasha (wicked person) must not be repeated, no matter what they are, because he probably said them with evil intent.  Is this accurate?  (Note that we say "ma tovu..." even though these words were said by Bilaam, the wicked gentile prophet, so we obviously don't always agree with that rabbi.)

Comment: The words of Elisha ben Abuya are repeated and some of his interpretations of the Tanakh are recorded as well in the Talmud.

Comment: @Akiva___ A heretic is not the same as a *rasha*. Also, many of the adages mentioned by Elisha ben Avuya were said before he became heretical.

Comment: @DanF Elisha ben Abuya helped the Romans destroy Judaism in Eretz Yisroel.  He was not just a heretic.   And some of his interpretations of the Tanakh were given while he was riding a horse on shabbos and R’ Meir followed him to listen and learn.

Comment: @DanF -- My question is: Did anybody say that?  The fact that we sometimes do it anyway does not mean some rabbis may not have disagreed.

Comment: Ah! I got the idea, now. Thanks for clarifying. That intention is really not clear in the title. You may want to edit it to state, "Did anyone state that..."

Comment: @Akiva___ Good points regarding EbA. However, see OP's response to me clarifying the intent of the question. Hopefully, he will edit.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59921/can-one-cite-divrei-torah-in-the-name-of-a-rabbi-who-has-gone-astray